# How can I figure out, if my phone recognises my headset correctly?

Tags: htc, headset

Phone: HTC Desire 510
Headset: Samsung EO-HS1303

Problem: Phone refuses to output stereo sound on that headset. 
Some exceptions: Occasionally after reboot and on first start of a few apps like bandcamp, there will be stereo sound. But only during the first track played.

Apparently the phone assumes to be connected to a monaural headset. How to find out why and how to fix it?

**Update:**
Phone is not rooted. Headset connected via 3.5 mm Jack. Headset works fine on Samsung Phone (one could expect that).

Comment: Rooted or not ?

Comment: Are you connecting it using the 3.5mm jack or Bluetooth ?

Comment: 3.5mm jack, not rooted.